# Edit function error

Tags: angular, spring-boot

im trying to get data about the user i want to edit in the form but it gets me an error about the same line of getting these data : **** this.user = data

---

this is  : edit-user.component.ts :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import {User} from '../../model/model.user';
 import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
 import {UsersService} from '../../services/users.service';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-edit-user',
 templateUrl: './edit-user.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./edit-user.component.css']
  })
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {
 mode = 1 ;
 user: User = new User ();
 idUser: number ;

 constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute , public userservice: 
 UsersService , public router: Router) {
this.idUser = activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'] ;
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.userservice.getUser(this.idUser)
  .subscribe(data => {
 this.user = data ;
 } , err => {
    console.log(err) ;
  }) ;
  }

 updateUser () {
 this.userservice.updateUser(this.user)
 .subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data) ;
  alert('User updated !') ;
  this.router.navigate(['users']) ;
  } , err => {
console.log(err);
alert('Error') ;
 }) ;
 }

 }
```

in users.component.ts i made that function related to the button :

```
   onEditUser (id: number) {
   this.router.navigate(['editUser', id]);
    }
```

in user.service.ts i made these two :

```
    getUser(id: number) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/users/' + id);
    }
     updateUser(user: User) {
     return this.http.put('http://localhost:8081/users/' + user.id , user);
   }
```

but i got this error in the line thhat i told u about  this.user = data

```
        src/app/edit-user/edit-user.component.ts(23,9): error TS2322: Type 
       'Object' is not assignable to type 'User'.

       The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean 
       to use the 'any' type instead?

       Property 'id' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
user: any={};
```

instead of

```
 user: User = new User ();
```

Comment: than mark it as right answer so it will help full to other.

Answer (score 0):

when you subscribe to `htt.get('url');`, it will return Response Object. so You need to parse it before passing to EditUserComponent.

Import map operator from RxJS in Service like this `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

then edit getUser method like below

```
    getUser(id: number) {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/users/' + id)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem! Happy Coding :)

Comment: i thought there is no need for .map in angular 5 ! it will be done automatically

Comment: even in angular 5 it still require.